How to load the webpack chunks in the external javascript file?
I am using the react with webpack and heres my webpack.config.js file:
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index",
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    allowedHosts: ['all'],
    port: 4000,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Allow requests from any origin
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
        "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization",
    },
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: [
                "@babel/preset-env" /* to transfer any advansed ES to ES5 */,
                "@babel/preset-react",
              ], // to compile react to ES5
              plugins: [
                ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs', { 'strictMode': false }]
              ]
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "Remote",
      filename: "moduleEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./App": "./src/App",
      },
      shared: {
        ...dependencies,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: dependencies["react"],
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: dependencies["react-dom"],
        },
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
    }),
    new WebpackManifestPlugin() 
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  target: "web",
};

and I have dist folder with all the chunks like for example src_App_js.js etc. I'm using React with WebPack. The react app has the ComponentA in it. ComponentA is simple HelloWorld app.
I want to render the App component externally like this :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Load Micro Frontend</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="appContainer"></div>
    <script>
        function loadMicroFrontend(props) {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = 'http://localhost:4000/src_App_js.js';
            script.onload = function () {
                renderMicroFrontend(props);
            };
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
        function renderMicroFrontend(props) {
            var app = window.Remote;
            if (app) {
                app.render(props.Component, props.ContainerId);
            } else {
                console.error('Micro frontend initialization failed.');
            }
        }
        var props = {
            Module: "Remote",
            Component: "App",
            ContainerId: "appContainer"
        };
        loadMicroFrontend(props);
    </script>
</body>
</html>

How to achieve this ? Am I missing something? Because this is getting me this error in console
Micro frontend initialization failed.
I have tried to load the chunks and I'm expecting the App to get rendered which is running on the remote react App. The App.js has the ComponentA like this:
This is my App.js:
import React from 'react'
import ComponentA from './ComponentA/ComponentA'
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentA />
    </div>
  )
}
export default App

This is my ComponentA.js:
import React from 'react'
function ComponentA() {
  return (
    <div>Hello World</div>
  )
}
export default ComponentA

